# How do I store levels in an Android game?

Tags: android

This isn't so much a technical question as it is a style question. I'm making a generalization of peg solitaire for Android, and there's going to be different levels you can play. Each of them will have different starting configurations for the board, different sets of moves you can do, etc.  Right now I have it programmed with a single basic level, and all those variables are initialized that way originally.

Do I add a text file that has all the different kinds of levels, and program it to read it from the text file? Do I add a Level class with all of this information from each level, and make several Level objects when it initializes? Do I make a Level class, but initialize it by reading the levels from a text file?

I'm sure all the methods would work, but is there a standard way to do it? I've never programmed anything like that before.

Comment: I'd do it by XML, then load it into a `Level` class. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: XML parsing is really slow on Android.

Comment: Avoid XML, I don't know Android but there should be another way to serialize you Level class, unsing more raw data.  
You did not talk about it but you need a level editor even a simple one. Once you have it, storing data and retrieving is not hard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There really isn't a standard way to do what you want, it really depends on the complexity of the data you need to store to do each level initialization. Is this data going to change or is it static? Does it make sense to have it properly organized and separated from code logic? These are questions you need to answer yourself cause it's your game and we don't know all the details.

Given that, you decide if you should store that data in an XML file, TXT file or something else. There really isn't a correct answer. But you should (IMO) always have some sort of `Level` class, that's the right way to go in a OOP context. The constructor could have the necessary parameters to build the level from the XML/TXT/whatever data. It could also have all the level parameters so you could initialize everything by code, if you need to for some reason. And, of course, don't forget the getter/setter methods for all those level attributes.

One thing I think you **shouldn't do** is to "make several Level objects when it initializes". You should separate your game logic from the data, you shouldn't mix both that way.

Probably not the answer you were looking for, but it's mostly up to you.

Comment: The data is static. If I don't make the objects when it initializes, when do I make them? Do you mean that I shouldn't have all of the level parameters explicitly written in initialization? Why do I need setter methods? Wouldn't I just use the constructor?

Comment: What I mean is what you assumed I meant ;) You could that for debugging purposes though, that's fine. But for your final code, you should separate your game logic from the data. It's just good practice. If you don't need setter methods, don't use them, I was being generic. But maybe they could come in handy if you need to change one or other for debugging purposes. This is all up to you, doesn't make much difference.

Answer (score 2):

The way my friends and I are doing it is storing the level attributes in a database then depending on which level the user selects, we read the database and load that into our Level class which creates the level for the user the play!

**Edit**

We're beginners as well, but it's been very easy to make new levels after the first one has been made. =] Especially since all we have to do is add a row to our database and fill in the values.